# ORMLite foreigncollection - object searching

Tags: ormlite, foreign-collection

I'm using ORMLite & SQLite as my database, and I'm working on a android app.

1) I'm searching for a particular object in the Foreign-Collection object as follows.

```
Collection<PantryCheckLine> pantryCheckLinesCollection = pantryCheck.getPantryCheckLines();
Iterator iterator = pantryCheckLinesCollection.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    pantryCheckLine = (PantryCheckLine) iterator.next();
    //i'm searching for a purticular object match   
}
```

2) Or else I can directly query from the relevant table and identified the item as well.

What I'm asking is out of these two methods which one will be much faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends a bit on the particulars of your situation.

- If your `ForeignCollection` is eager fetched then your loop will not have to do any database transactions and will, for small collections, probably be faster then doing the query.
- However if your collection lazy loaded then iterating through the collection will go back to the database anyway so you might as well do the precise query.